# Weird characters after implementing bootloader Assembly OS

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, osdev

I just implemented a bootloader in my small Assembly OS. It appears to be working, since it boots straight in the kernel. There is one problem, the characters are not correct, this was not a problem before the implementation of the bootloader, since the operating system also acted as a bootloader (but had to do the two things separately because of the 512 bytes limitation).

[This is how it looked like before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRLkim.jpg) vs. [how it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSm9pm.jpg).

I didn't modified at all the kernel apart from the boot signature (or I have to keep it?) And the line that fills the remaining space with zeroes.
I have no clue of what could be the issue...

Here is the kernel I used:

```
MOV AX, 0     ; Set up segment registers
MOV DS, AX
MOV ES, AX
MOV SS, AX
MOV SP, 0x7C00
 
InputBufferSize equ 32  ; Set input buffer size
 
CALL PrintWelcomeMessage    ; Call function to print welcome message
CALL PrintCommandPrompt     ; Call function to print command prompt
 
JMP $         ; Loop forever
 
; Function to print welcome message
PrintWelcomeMessage:
  MOV SI, WelcomeMessage     ; Load address of welcome message
 
PrintWelcomeLoop:
  LODSB                      ; Load character from SI
  OR AL, AL                  ; Check for null terminator
  JZ WelcomeDone             ; If null terminator, we are done
  MOV AH, 09                 ; Function 9 (Text color and attributes)
  MOV BX, 001Fh              ; Set the text color
  INT 10h
  MOV AH, 0x0E               ; BIOS interrupt code for printing character
  MOV BH, 0x00               ; Display page number
  MOV BL, 0x07               ; Text attribute (white on black)
  INT 0x10                   ; Call interrupt to print character
  JMP PrintWelcomeLoop       ; Repeat for the next character
 
WelcomeDone:
  JE NEWLINE
  RET
 
; Function to print command prompt
PrintCommandPrompt:
  MOV SI, CommandPrompt      ; Load address of command prompt
  CALL PrintString           ; Call function to print string
  JMP READ_INPUT             ; Jump to function to read user input
 
  ;THIS PART IS VERY IMPORTANT, IT WILL HANDLE COMMANDS;
  ; Function to handle user input
  HANDLE_INPUT:
   MOV DI, InputBuffer   ; Load address of input buffer
   CMP BYTE [DI], 'h'    ; Check if input is 'h'
   JNE NO_COMMAND       ; Jump to prompt if not "h"
   CALL PrintHelp       ; Call function to print help information
   JNE NEWLINE
   JMP READ_INPUT       ; Jump back to prompt
 
  PRINT_PROMPT:
   JE NEWLINE
   MOV SI, CommandPrompt ; Load address of command prompt
   CALL PrintString      ; Call function to print command prompt
   RET
 
  NO_COMMAND:
   MOV SI, CommandNotFound ; Load address of CommandNotFound
   CALL PrintString
   JMP PRINT_PROMPT
   RET
 
  VERSION_COMMAND:
   MOV DI, InputBuffer   ; Load address of input buffer
   CMP BYTE [DI], 'v'    ; Check if input is 'v'
   JNE NO_COMMAND       ; Jump to prompt if not "v"
   CALL PrintVersion       ; Call function to print Version information
   JNE NEWLINE
   JMP READ_INPUT       ; Jump back to prompt
 
  PrintHelp:
   MOV SI, HelpPrompt    ; Load address of help prompt
   CALL PrintString      ; Call function to print help prompt
   JMP PRINT_PROMPT      ; Jump back to prompt after printing help prompt
   RET
 
  PrintVersion:
   MOV SI, Version    ; Load address of Version prompt
   CALL PrintString      ; Call function to print Version prompt
   JMP PRINT_PROMPT      ; Jump back to prompt after printing Version prompt
   RET
 
; Function to read input from user
READ_INPUT:
 
  MOV AH, 09                 ; Function 9 (Text color and attributes)
  MOV BX, 00Fh               ; Set the text color
  INT 10h
 
  MOV AH, 0x00               ; BIOS interrupt code for reading character
  INT 0x16                   ; Call interrupt to read character
  CMP AL, 0x0D               ; Check for newline character
  JE HANDLE_INPUT
  JE NEWLINE                 ; If newline, print new line
  CMP AL, 0x08               ; Check for backspace character
  JE BACKSPACE
  MOV [InputBuffer], AL      ; Store character in buffer
  MOV SI, InputBuffer        ; Load address of input buffer
  CALL PrintString           ; Call function to print user input
  JMP READ_INPUT             ; Repeat until newline
 
READ_LOOP:
  MOV AH, 0x00             ; BIOS interrupt code for reading character
  INT 0x16                 ; Call interrupt to read character
  CMP AL, 0x0D             ; Check for newline character
  JE NEWLINE               ; If newline, print new line
  MOV [DI], AL             ; Store character in buffer
  INC DI                   ; Increment buffer pointer
  INC CX                   ; Increment input length
  CMP CX, InputBufferSize  ; Check if input buffer is full
  JE READ_DONE             ; If buffer is full, exit loop
  JMP READ_LOOP            ; Repeat until newline or buffer is full
 
NEWLINE:
  MOV SI, NewLine            ; Load address of NewLine string
  MOV AH, 0x0E               ; BIOS interrupt code for printing character
  MOV BH, 0x00               ; Display page number
  MOV BL, 0x07               ; Text attribute (white on black)
  MOV AL, 0x0D               ; Carriage return character
  INT 0x10                   ; Call interrupt to print carriage return
  MOV AL, 0x0A               ; Newline character
  INT 0x10                   ; Call interrupt to print newline
  CALL PrintString
  MOV SI, CommandPrompt      ; Load address of command prompt
  CALL PrintString           ; Call function to print command prompt
  JMP READ_INPUT             ; Repeat until newline or buffer is full
 
BACKSPACE:
  CMP CL, 0                  ; No characters in the line?
  JE READ_INPUT              ; Return to the read loop
  DEC DI
 
  MOV AH, 09                 ; Function 9 (Text color and attributes)
  MOV BX, 0000               ; Set the text color
  INT 10h
 
  MOV BYTE [DI], 0           ; Delete the character
  MOV AH, 0x0E
  MOV AL, 0x08
  INT 10h
  MOV AL, ''
  INT 10h
  MOV AL, 0x08
  INT 10h
  JMP READ_INPUT
 
READ_DONE:
  MOV BYTE [DI], 0x00           ; Add null terminator to input string
  RET
 
; Function to print a null-terminated string
PrintString:
  LODSB                      ; Load character from SI
  OR AL, AL                  ; Check for null terminator
  JZ PrintStringDone         ; If null terminator, return
  MOV AH, 0x0E               ; BIOS interrupt code for printing character
  MOV BH, 0x00               ; Display page number
  MOV BL, 0x07               ; Text attribute (white on black)
  INT 0x10                   ; Call interrupt to print character
  JMP PrintString            ; Repeat until null terminator
 
PrintStringDone:
  RET
 
;----Output messages----;
HelpPrompt DB ' List of commands: (add something)', 0
WelcomeMessage DB 'Welcome', 0
CommandPrompt DB 'Command: ', 0
CommandNotFound DB ' Non-Existing command', 0
Version DB 'Add version', 0
 
;----String constants----;
NewLine       DB 0x0D, 0x0A, 0
 
InputBufferSize equ 32                ; Set input buffer size
InputBuffer db InputBufferSize dup(0) ; Reserve space for input buffer
```

And here is the small bootloader:

```
ORG 0x7C00       

start:
    xor ax, ax      ; Clear ax register
    mov ss, ax      ; Set stack segment to 0
    mov sp, 0x7C00  ; Set stack pointer to boot sector address

    ; Load the second-stage bootloader
    mov ah, 0x02    ; BIOS read sector function
    mov al, 1       ; Number of sectors to read
    mov ch, 0       ; Cylinder number
    mov dh, 0       ; Head number
    mov bx, 0x1000  ; Address to load the second-stage bootloader
    mov es, bx      ; Set es register to the segment of the destination address
    xor bx, bx      ; Offset in es:bx set to 0

    int 0x13        ; BIOS Interrupt to read HD

    ; Jump to the loaded program (OS)
    jmp 0x1000:0000

times 510-($-$$) db 0  ; Fill with zeroes
dw 0xAA55              ; Boot signature
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it got flagged as a spam and i couldn't upload it"? I do not see how a spam flag can come in if you [edit] to show a [mre] as formatted (see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ) code text in your question. I assume you are referring to a previous question post of yours, which is now deleted. Please provide a link to it. Do not worry about it being deleted, I can see it nevertheless if you link it. Then I have a look at what happened there.

Comment: Sorry, I am not interested in the code itself. I am interested in "it got flagged as a spam and i couldn't upload it". I want to help you with that unlikely problem. Please provide info, ideally a link to the question post. Independent of that, please try to [edit] and provide the code as formatted (link to info above) text directly in your question. The only obstacle is if you use a lot of code and too little prose explanation. That however is very different from "it got flagged as spam".

Comment: Voted to ReOpen because code to be debugged is now available.

Comment: Question does not contain loader source nor build and run commands. At a guess, an `org` directive may be needed. The value however will depend on where the kernel is loaded (by the loader).

Comment: I am very sorry if i didn't provided more information before, next time i will be more careful

Comment: You're loading to and jumping to `1000h:0` aka linear address 1_0000h. It is expected that with `es` = `ds` = 0 as written by your kernel, you cannot possibly access its variables as in regular Real 86 Mode you are limited to offsets <= FFFFh, and that's below your load linear address of 1_0000h. Also, you should initialise `cl` to 2, and not initialise `dl` for int 13h at all to retain the value passed to your loader by the prior loader. If you use no `org` directive in the kernel (equivalent to `org 0`), you want to set `es` = `ds` = 1000h.